# add/editing 2 db tables in one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Noob here. I'm building a recipe website and am having issues with 1 little piece. If you have the time to point me in the right direction it would be great.

I have a recipe table with title, desc, photo, time to prepare.

I also have a ingredients table with amount, modifier (eg cups, ml), ingredient, modifier2 (chopped, diced, etc)

I wasn't to be able to add/edit a recipe and its ingredients in 1 page and have it populate both tables.

I'm assuming its dead simple and I'm just overlooking something basic.

I don't need a verbose answer, just pointing on the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look up nested forms:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Short pseudo example:

```
# model
attr_accessible :ingredients_attributes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients

# controller
def new
  @recipe = Recipe.new
  @recipe.ingredients.build
end

# new.html.erb
<% form_for(@recipe) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field(:name) %>
  <% fields_for(@recipie.ingredients) do |r|
    <%= r.text_field(:amount) %>
    <%= r.text_field(:name) %>
  <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Using rails4 you need to move attr_accessible into the controller (def private)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ingredients
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
end
```

You can check out the docs [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).